Excel VBA fIlling SeriesCollection is too slow! How to improve chart performance when there are many SeriesCollections filled in RunTime
Quest: use the Speedtest and make it go faster, than it does right now.
Info
My PC is quite fast. I have a chart of the type column.
The whole values for the chart as well as the values for the table are calculated in VBA and the table itself can not be loaded in to a chart because of its design. So we need to get the values in there with VBA.
Each month in a 4 year period is represented in the chart multiplied by 2 because there are two different modes. Making up 8 Series for each Data displayed. (This is kinda inevitable)
There are about 25 different items of data displayed this way and filtered by the user using buttons using the Is.Filtered function of the chart in a smart way for nice displaying.
The Chart
Problem: the Chart is too slow adding all the data (it does only once upon its creating occurring only when the data changes).
Question #1: is there a way to disable the chart from reloading all the time when adding a new series?
Question #2: is it possible to define the SeriesCollection beforehand and then add it in once, causing the chart to also only refresh once?
What have I tried

Application.EnableEvents = False, ScreenUpdate and other don't speed up the process at all
I tried creating a new SeriesCollection, or copying one from an existing chart and paste it in to another but I guess you can't do Chart1.SeriesCollection = Chart2.SeriesCollection. It says it is not supported.
Using set for the new variables makes it connect to the chart keeping it reloading
I tried on the creation of the new series to filter it instantly. This only takes even longer

Here is a debug function that adds series to a chart for speed testing. My result is about 650ms that's too long!. Focus on the top code block the two down there are just functions for the speed test, you'll might need those for testing though:
Sub TestDiagramPerformance()

    With Tabelle2.ChartObjects("TestDiagram").Chart

        'Delete ALL Data (For Retesting)
        For Each s In .FullSeriesCollection: s.Delete: Next s

    Call DebugTimer(True, "Test") 'Start Timer

        'Add Series
        For fi = 1 To 250:
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .SeriesCollection(fi).XValues = 500 'THIS TAKES TOO LONG!
         .SeriesCollection(fi).Values = 10 'THIS TAKES TOO LONG!
        Next
            
    End With
    
    Call DebugTimer(False, "Test") 'Finish Timer and display Time
    
End Sub

'This is the DebugTimer (works Fine, just for testing)
'Public Sub DebugTimer(StartOrEnd As Boolean, Optional AdditionalName = 1, Optional Priority = 1)
'If ReadName("DebugSettings_IsTimerEnabled") = False Then Exit Sub
'If ReadName("DebugSettings_EnabledTimerPriorities") < Priority Then Exit Sub
' Name = "DebugTimer_" & AdditionalName
'    Select Case StartOrEnd
'    Case True
'            Application.Names.Add _
'            Name:=Name, _
'            RefersTo:=Timer 'No Process Time Since is Last Line
'    Case False
'        nv = Application.Names(Name).Value
'        n = Split(Mid(nv, 2, Len(nv) - 1), ".")
'        If (UBound(n) > 0) Then
'         XN = n(0) & "," & n(1)
'         Debug.Print Name, Format(((Timer - XN)) * 1000, "#####.## ms")
'        Else
'         Debug.Print "An Error Occured in the DebugTimer"
'        End If
'        Application.Names(Name).Delete 'Process Time consuming circa 4 seconds on my device
'    End Select
'End Sub

'ReadName Funciton (works fine, Used in DebugTimer)
'Public Function ReadName(Name)
'v = Application.Names(Name).Value
'        If Left(v, 2) = "=" & chr$(34) Then  'Wenn Normal (Text) "="text"" oder "="416,67""
'    OutPut = Mid(v, 3, Len(v) - 3) 'Read TextFormat
'         If OutPut = str(True) Or OutPut = str(False) Then ReadName = CBool(OutPut): Exit Function  'Wenn Bool Return Convert to Bool
'        Else 'Wenn Number Format "=100"
'    OutPut = Mid(v, 2, Len(v) - 1) 'ReadNumber
'        End If
'    If IsNumeric(OutPut) And InStr(1, OutPut, ".") Then OutPut = Replace(OutPut, ".", ",") 'Regain Comma
'    If IsNumeric(OutPut) Then OutPut = CDbl(OutPut) 'Convert to Double on Numeric
'ReadName = OutPut
'End Function


Can't you write the data into an extra sheet and link the chart to that?

Not exactly your design, but much faster. Just to make sure i understood what you want us the test, look at this as a first try. In this case the data is read from a worksheet, u just said you need it to be done from vba itself, but we can fix this later. My PC is not as fast as yours, but i accomplish this in less than 10 ms:
Sub QuickFill()

Dim dStart  As Double
Dim dEnd    As Double

    dStart = Timer
    
    With Tabelle2.ChartObjects("Diagramm").Chart
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Tabelle2!$A$1:$A$250"
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Tabelle2!$B$1:$B$250"
    End With

    dEnd = Timer
    Debug.Print dEnd - dStart
    
End Sub

The data is in the table and looks like this:


Not sure I follow either your Q1 ir your Q2. However no need to delete Series each time if, as seems from your example, the main objective is to change existing values. FWIW the 'Timer' function is a low res timer at roughly 0.05sec, Gettickcount is fairly low res roughly 16ms.
Private Declare PtrSafe Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetTickCount" () As Long

Sub Test2()
Dim i As Long, cnt As Long, t As Long
Dim sr As Series
Dim cht As Chart

    t = getTickCount
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    
    With cht
        For Each sr In .SeriesCollection
            cnt = cnt + 1
            If cnt > 250 Then
                sr.Delete
            Else
                sr.XValues = 500
                sr.Values = 10
            End If
        Next
        
        If cnt < 250 Then
            For i = cnt + 1 To 250
                Set sr = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                sr.XValues = 500
                sr.Values = 10
            Next
        End If
    End With
    
    Debug.Print getTickCount - t

End Sub


I found a workaround to my question
It is inevitable to create the SeriesCollections. So the answer with only putting it in one SeriesCollection would generally work, but would not display the chart the way it is supposed to, since these are grouped columns, that need a SeriesCollection for each Column to be displayed, while each SeriesCollection contains an array of data for each month.
The problem is that Excel keeps reloading the entire chart, each time you add a new SeriesCollection. It seems to be impossible to stop it to do so. So I decided to leave 8 (Modes * Years) SeriesCollections instead of having 8 of these for each Data, present in the table, which were being filled up upon creation before.
Therefore I outsourced the entire data in to a table, which was previously loaded in the chart and filtered upon user input.
Important to note is, that during runtime I first load all the data in to a two-dimensional array that has the structure of an array you get when putting a range in an array:
Dim MyRangeArray(): ReDim Preserve MyRangeArray(1 to AmountRows, 1 to AmountColumns)

Second: pass the entire array in to the range so Excel does not have to write every single line. Otherwise it will probably have a bad performance.
Tabelle1.Range("A3:M253") = MyRangeArray


Upon user input I now assign the name and values of my 8 SeriesCollections from the table, causing the Chart to 'only' reload 16 times and only load 8 SeriesCollections each time instead of 500 times loading 250 SeriesCollecitons. Reducing the entire process time from 800+ms to roughly 35 ms (I filter the table with VBA and assign the values to the chart as values of the type double not as pointer to a range)
Afterword
This workaround sadly requires a second chart to hold the data. I tried to put the Array in to a formularname of the Namemanager but there is too much data for a FormulaName to hold it. It is weird that excel is not able to have the chart hold the data, without huge performance loss. There also is a limit for how many SeriesCollections can be contained within a chart. Also weird that the CalculationManual mode does not stop the chart from reloading each and every single thing in the chart.

I don't really follow your objective but whatever it is I suspect there might be other ways. Some terminology: a SeriesCollection, as the name suggests, is a collection of Series, each Series can have one or multiple Points. Although only one SeriesCollection for the entire chart each ChartObject (collection of similar Series types column, line etc) also has a SeriesCollection, a subset of the main collection. Have you looked into changing Series' formulas as a way of changing chart data, or use of 'dynamic' Named ranges in series formulas. FWIW my example here was c.40ms to update.
